# Почему svg спрайты не видны на сервере

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, svg-спрайт

Возникла такая проблема:  svg sprite'ы не видны в браузерах,  кроме самого gulp.
Вот то что на хостинге ====>

[image: hosting]

А вот уже включеный галп и все прекрасно работает ===>
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрипт для добавления спрайтов в body

```
;( function( window, document )
{
'use strict';

var file     = 'img/symbols.svg',
    revision = 1;

if( !document.createElementNS || !document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg' ).createSVGRect )
    return true;

var isLocalStorage = 'localStorage' in window && window[ 'localStorage' ] !== null,
    request,
    data,
    insertIT = function()
    {
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', data );
    },
    insert = function()
    {
        if( document.body ) insertIT();
        else document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', insertIT );
    };

if( isLocalStorage && localStorage.getItem( 'inlineSVGrev' ) == revision )
{
    data = localStorage.getItem( 'inlineSVGdata' );
    if( data )
    {
        insert();
        return true;
    }
}

try
{
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open( 'GET', file, true );
    request.onload = function()
    {
        if( request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400 )
        {
            data = request.responseText;
            insert();
            if( isLocalStorage )
            {
                localStorage.setItem( 'inlineSVGdata',  data );
                localStorage.setItem( 'inlineSVGrev',   revision );
            }
        }
    }
    request.send();
}
catch( e ){}

}( window, document ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте простую проверку: откройте файл спрайта `symbols.svg`  с помощью  любого браузера.  Если изображения иконок не появятся, то это и есть ответ на ваш вопрос. 
Код иконки, который обернут тегами `<symbol>... </symbol>` не отображается по умолчанию. 
Это основная роль этого тега - не показывать изображение svg до вызова его с помощью команды `use`

**Обычная работа со спрайтами выглядит так:**

Добавляем файл  спрайта в Html страницу

`<object type="image/svg+xml"  data="img/symbols.svg"></object>`

Вызываем любую иконку из спрайта

```
<section class="advantages">
<div class="container"> 
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <use xlink:href="img/symbols.svg#advatage-1"></use>
</svg> 
</div>
  <div class="container">
  <svg>
      <use xlink:href="img/symbols.svg#advatage-2"></use>
  </svg> 
</div>
</section>
```